# Local socket connection between a Python program and JS

Tags: javascript, sockets

I'm trying to establish a socket connection between Python (Client) and JavaScript (Server), but I'm a little bit confused how to do it.

On the serverside in javascript I have this code:

**JS Server**

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
        socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
        socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

And for the client side on Python I have this

**Python Client**

```
import socket

class JavaSocket:

def __init__(self):
    self.client_socket = None
    self.portNumber = 1337

def socketMethod(self):
    """ This method will establish the socket Connection between Java and Python """
    try:
        self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client_socket.connect(("localhost",self.portNumber))
        print(self.portNumber)
    except Exception as e:
        raise

def socketConnection(self):

    sentence = "Test"
    self.client_socket.send(sentence.encode())
    data = self.client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(data)
    if data is not None:
        print("Socket closed")
    self.client_socket.close()


js = JavaSocket()
js.socketMethod()
js.socketConnection()
```

I'm not really familiar with JS and socket connections. I tried running this in Python and got an error indicating that the connection was refused.

Comment: Why are you piping the socket to the socket ?  `socket.pipe(socket);` and once the socket is created, you can listen for data, using `socket.on('data', callback)`

Comment: I don't know. I got the JS code from https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757. I had the same question but it seemed to work to others

Comment: Ah! `socket.pipe(socket);` is to send back to the client what was received, for testing.

Comment: And the node.js code is working as expected, tested on linux with `telnet 127.0.0.1 1337`. So you may check if the port is not firewalled or not available from the client

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help. Would I still need  `socket.on('data', callback)`?

Comment: if you want to handle received data, yes.

Comment: @krampstudio How can you print the message received to the console? I've been trying to search for it but can't find a correct solution. Thanks!

Comment: `socket.on('data', function(buffer) { console.log(buffer.toString()) };`

Comment: Did you find the original issue preventing you to connect ? If yes, could you please post the answer. If you just need assistance in programming in js, this is outside of stackoverflow scope.

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Could you please post it (you can answer to your own question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the client server side that I worked for me was

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
    socket.on('data', function(buffer)
        {
             console.log(buffer.toString());
         }
    });

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

This would connect to the client and send the "Echo server" message and print the message "Test" from the client